# Which functions can be obtained as convolution?

Tags: real-analysis, convolution

Let us consider the function $I(x):=\frac{1}{2\epsilon}1_{[-\epsilon, \epsilon]}(x)$.
Which are the functions $g: \mathbb R \to [0,1]$ such that

$$g(x) = f*I(x)$$

for some $f: \mathbb R \to [0,1]$?

It can be proved, by the fundamental theorem of integral calculus that, any $g$ of this form must be $\frac{1}{\epsilon}-$lipschitz, but I do not think this condition is sufficient.

Comment: How about applying the Fourier transform?

Comment: I'm trying, but it is difficult to verify the fact that $f(x)\in  [0,1]$

Comment: Why do you think that the set of these convolutions can be characterized reasonably? What do you need this for?